# Rails and Angular can't get URL route id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm trying to get the ID from my URL in my Angular routing after being passed to the page from Rails routing. However, I'm having trouble retrieving the id and I've tried all sorts of different combinations for the url matching. Is there a way for me to log out the URL and to try and figure out how I should be matching the urls?

Sample link: `http://localhost:3000/events/dumpling_night`

Rails route:

```
get '/events/*path' => 'event#event'
```

Angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngRoute', 'templates']);

app.config([
  '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {  
    console.log($routeProvider.$get);
    $routeProvider.
     when('/:id', { //trying to render this, but keeps going to .otherwise
        templateUrl: '../templates/eventTemp2.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl2'
     }).
     otherwise({
        templateUrl: '../templates/eventTemp.html',
        controller: 'EventsCtrl'
     });
  }
]);
app.controller('EventsCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('yo!');
});

app.controller('EventsCtrl2', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log('yo2');
});
```

Rails events controller:

```
class EventController < ApplicationController
    layout "application"
    def event
    end
end
```

Comment: In your angular code, shouldn't it be `'/events/:id'` instead of `':id'`?

Comment: ...and now it magically works. Thanks @geeky_sh!